# Scala: “any” and “all” functions

Tags: scala, functional-programming

my Haskell* is a bit rusty, so i can imagine that I’m missing the obvious:

```
def any[A](s: Traversable[A], f: A => Boolean): Boolean = {
    s.foldLeft(false)((bool, elem) => bool || f(elem))
}
```

Does one of these properties apply to the it?

1. predefined somewhere in the Scala libs
2. circumstantial, and faster written as some one-liner
3. wrong (I didn’t test it, sorry ;))

---

*actually SML, but that’s 99% the same, but known by nobody under the sun.

Comment: If you think Haskell is 99% SML, you either haven't gotten to monads yet or rate underlying principles way higher than the way actual code looks and works like (e.g. you'd also consider Java 99% C++).

Comment: how does haskell or SML are related to this question ( perhaps I'm missing the obvious )

Comment: well, let’s say that 99% of SML is **in** Haskell ;)

Comment: i remember writing similar (=functional) code in SML. That’s why i’m not completely alien to functional programming and not disturbed when having to pass a function as parameter to another)

Comment: Haskell and SML are quite different since Haskell is lazy by default.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

1. It's predefined and is called `exists`. And `forall` would be the "all" function you are looking for.

   ```
   scala> Vector(3, 4, 5).exists(_ % 2 == 0)
   res1: Boolean = true

   scala> Vector(3, 4, 5).forall(_ % 2 == 0)
   res2: Boolean = false
   ```
2. You can make it more performant using a `for` loop with a `break` (from `scala.util.control.Breaks`). (See the standard library implementation of `exists` and `forall`.)
3. It's correct.

Comment: a for loop, how conventional :). I don’t know if you brought up `exists` and `forall` first (@rafalotufo’s answer was edited to include it). how should i behave in this case? can’t accept both.

Comment: In TraversableLike, exists is short-circuited.

Comment: I wonder if there's also a built in `.all` with no arguments.

Comment: @ErikAllik, there isn't.

Comment: @ErikAllik it would be nice to have an .all with no arguments for `Traversable[Boolean]`, but I was not able to find it.

Answer (score 6):

Methods exist on the Traversable trait which are equivalent to `any` and `all`:

```
def all[A](xs: Traversable[A], p: A => Boolean): Boolean = xs forall p

def any[A](xs: Traversable[A], p: A => Boolean): Boolean = xs exists p
```

Answer (score 2):

1. No it isn't predifined with those names. You can use `exists` from Traversable package.
2. The biggest disadvantage of your implementation is that will necessary consume all of your traversible, when, for `any`, if any is true, if could already give you your answer. The same goes for `all`. But one could easily implement this so that it doesn't evaluate the whole sequence. Another solution would be to implement a monad for this type of operation. Then you would call:

   `a and b and c` which is equivalent to `a.and(b).and(c)`
3. It is correct.

BTW, another function that I find missing is a `sum` function.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll accept this one as soon as Stackoverflow lets me do so. Double thanks for the hint on early exiting. An idea how to do it elegantly?

Comment: And `someTraversable.reduceLeft(_+_)` is a bit clumsier than `someTraversable.sum`, but I don’t think it’s worth to define a function (unlike for `any` and `all`, which seem to be quite a bit lengthier). Note that I *would* like to see `sum`, `product` and stuff in `scala.Predef`, too, only I’d not define it myself if it isnNt there.

Comment: The standard library does have the `sum` function. (Resides in `GenTraversableOnce`.)

Comment: @flying sheep: the most elegant way would be to just use the `exists` function, which probably checks for that. If you want to implement it your self, you will need to use standard looping mechanism and break the loop when you found `true`.

Answer (score 1):

How about `exists`:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).exists(_ > 2)
res12: Boolean = true
```

It's on [Traversable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Traversable.html).